# Jquery - как дважды использовать один скрипт в разных блоках

Tags: jquery

У меня на сайте 13 блоков , при нажатие на кнопку выводится попап. Как сделать чтобы каждый раз новый попап с новыми данными открывался вот скрипт.

```css
/* COLORS
========================================== */
/* MIXINS
========================================== */
/* KEYFRAMES
========================================== */
@-webkit-keyframes float {
  0% {
    transform: translatey(0px);
    transform: translatex(0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translatey(-30px);
    transform: translatex(20px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translatey(0px);
    transform: translatex(0px);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes float {
  0% {
    transform: translatey(0px);
    transform: translatex(0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translatey(-30px);
    transform: translatex(20px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translatey(0px);
    transform: translatex(0px);
  }
}
@-o-keyframes float {
  0% {
    transform: translatey(0px);
    transform: translatex(0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translatey(-30px);
    transform: translatex(20px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translatey(0px);
    transform: translatex(0px);
  }
}
@keyframes float {
  0% {
    transform: translatey(0px);
    transform: translatex(0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translatey(-30px);
    transform: translatex(20px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translatey(0px);
    transform: translatex(0px);
  }
}

/* BUTTON
========================================== */
.button {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;

    margin-top: 40px;
}
.button button {
     position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-family: inherit;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 0;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: #8e6ac1;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s;
    transition: all 0.4s;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #8e6ac1;
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.button button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #8e6ac1;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.button button span {
  opacity: 1;
}
.button.clicked button {
  visibility: hidden;
  oacity: 0;
}


.button1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;

    margin-top: 40px;
}
.button1 button {
     position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-family: inherit;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 0;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: #8e6ac1;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s;
    transition: all 0.4s;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #8e6ac1;
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.button1 button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #8e6ac1;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.button1 button span {
  opacity: 1;
}
.button1.clicked button {
  visibility: hidden;
  oacity: 0;
}



/* POP-UP
========================================== */
.pop-up {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.9);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.9);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.9);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.9);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.9);
  overflow-y: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.pop-up1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.9);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.9);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.9);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.9);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.9);
  overflow-y: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .pop-up {
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
    height: auto;
    max-width: 900px;
  }
}
.pop-up .content {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 900px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .pop-up .content {
    min-height: inherit;
  }
}
.pop-up .content .container {
  padding: 100px 20px 140px;
}
@media (min-width: 568px) {
  .pop-up .content .container {
    padding: 50px 20px 80px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .pop-up .content .container {
    padding: 70px 0px 90px;
    max-width: 520px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
.pop-up .content .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.05rem;
  color: #3e4146;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}
.pop-up .content .close:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #f66867;
}
.pop-up .content .dots .dot {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%;
  z-index: 11;
}
.pop-up .content .dots .dot:nth-of-type(1) {
  top: -80px;
  right: -80px;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  background-color: #689bf6;
  -webkit-animation: float 6s ease-in-out infinite;
  -moz-animation: float 6s ease-in-out infinite;
  -o-animation: float 6s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation: float 6s ease-in-out infinite;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .pop-up .content .dots .dot:nth-of-type(1) {
    top: -190px;
    right: -190px;
    width: 380px;
    height: 380px;
  }
}
.pop-up .content .dots .dot:nth-of-type(2) {
  bottom: -120px;
  left: -120px;
  width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
  background-color: #f66867;
  -webkit-animation: float 8s ease-in-out infinite;
  -moz-animation: float 8s ease-in-out infinite;
  -o-animation: float 8s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation: float 8s ease-in-out infinite;
}
.pop-up .content .dots .dot:nth-of-type(3) {
  bottom: -50px;
  right: -50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ffd84c;
  -webkit-animation: float 4s ease-in-out infinite;
  -moz-animation: float 4s ease-in-out infinite;
  -o-animation: float 4s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation: float 4s ease-in-out infinite;
}
.pop-up .content .title h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #f66867;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 2.8rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.05rem;
}
.pop-up .content img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 220px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px 0 40px 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(60px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(60px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(60px);
  -o-transform: translateX(60px);
  transform: translateX(60px);
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s;
  transition: 0.2s;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .pop-up .content img {
    max-width: 300px;
  }
}
.pop-up .content .subscribe h1 {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: #3e4146;
  line-height: 130%;
  letter-spacing: 0.07rem;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.pop-up .content .subscribe h1 span {
  color: #f66867;
}
.pop-up .content .subscribe form {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.pop-up .content .subscribe form input {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.05rem;
  outline: 0;
}
.pop-up .content .subscribe form input[type=email] {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #bec1c5;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .pop-up .content .subscribe form input[type=email] {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    width: 75%;
    border-right-width: 0px;
  }
}
.pop-up .content .subscribe form input[type=email]:focus {
  border-color: #3e4146;
}
.pop-up .content .subscribe form input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #8e6ac1;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #8e6ac1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .pop-up .content .subscribe form input[type=submit] {
    width: 25%;
  }
}
.pop-up .content .subscribe form input[type=submit]:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #7349af;
  border-color: #7349af;
}
.pop-up.open {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}
.pop-up.open img {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  -moz-transition: 1s;
  -o-transition: 1s;
  transition: 1s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(0px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0px);
  -o-transform: translateX(0px);
  transform: translateX(0px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="media">
 <div class="media1">
  <ul>
   <li><i class="fab fa-facebook-f" style="font-size: 80px;color: #333333;
    margin-bottom: 10px;"></i></li>
   <li style="color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8);font-size: 26px;font-weight: 600;">Facebook</li>
   <li><div class="button">
   <button><span>Посмотреть цены</span></button>

    </div>

    <div class="pop-up">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="dots">
            <div class="dot"></div>
            <div class="dot"></div>
            <div class="dot"></div>
          </div>
          
          <span class="close">close</span>
          
          <div class="title">
            <h1>Накрутит в Facebook</h1>
          </div>
          
          <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/256492/cXsiNryL.png" alt="Car">
          
          <div class="subscribe">
            <h1>Subscribe to get the latest <span>news &amp; updates</span>.</h1>
          
            <form>
              <input type="email" placeholder="Your email address">
              <input type="submit" value="Subscribe">
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</li>

  </ul>
  <script>
 $('button').click(function(){
  $('.pop-up').addClass('open');
});

$('.pop-up .close').click(function(){
  $('.pop-up').removeClass('open');
});
</script>
 </div>




  <div class="media1">
  <ul>
   <li><i class="fab fa-facebook-f" style="font-size: 80px;color: #333333;
    margin-bottom: 10px;"></i></li>
   <li style="color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8);font-size: 26px;font-weight: 600;">Instagram</li>
   <li><div class="button">
   <button><span>Посмотреть цены</span></button>
    </div>

    <div class="pop-up1">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="dots">
            <div class="dot"></div>
            <div class="dot"></div>
            <div class="dot"></div>
          </div>
          
          <span class="close">close</span>
          
          <div class="title">
            <h1>Накрутить в инстаграм</h1>
          </div>
          
          <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/256492/cXsiNryL.png" alt="Car">
          
          <div class="subscribe">
            <h1>Subscribe to get the latest <span>news &amp; updates</span>.</h1>
          
            <form>
              <input type="email" placeholder="Your email address">
              <input type="submit" value="Subscribe">
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</li>
  
  </ul>
  <script>
 $('button').click(function(){
  $('.pop-up').addClass('open');
});

$('.pop-up .close').click(function(){
  $('.pop-up').removeClass('open');
});

</script>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $('.media1 li .button button').click(function() {
    $(this).closest("li").find('.pop-up').addClass('open');
  });

  $('.pop-up .close').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.pop-up').removeClass('open');
  });
});
```

```css
/* COLORS
========================================== */


/* MIXINS
========================================== */


/* KEYFRAMES
========================================== */

@-webkit-keyframes float {
  0% {
    transform: translatey(0px);
    transform: translatex(0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translatey(-30px);
    transform: translatex(20px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translatey(0px);
    transform: translatex(0px);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes float {
  0% {
    transform: translatey(0px);
    transform: translatex(0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translatey(-30px);
    transform: translatex(20px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translatey(0px);
    transform: translatex(0px);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes float {
  0% {
    transform: translatey(0px);
    transform: translatex(0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translatey(-30px);
    transform: translatex(20px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translatey(0px);
    transform: translatex(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes float {
  0% {
    transform: translatey(0px);
    transform: translatex(0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translatey(-30px);
    transform: translatex(20px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translatey(0px);
    transform: translatex(0px);
  }
}


/* BUTTON
========================================== */

.button {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.button button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-family: inherit;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: #8e6ac1;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #8e6ac1;
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.button button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #8e6ac1;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.button button span {
  opacity: 1;
}

.button.clicked button {
  visibility: hidden;
  oacity: 0;
}

.button1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.button1 button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-family: inherit;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: #8e6ac1;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #8e6ac1;
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.button1 button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #8e6ac1;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.button1 button span {
  opacity: 1;
}

.button1.clicked button {
  visibility: hidden;
  oacity: 0;
}


/* POP-UP
========================================== */

.pop-up {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.9);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.9);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.9);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.9);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.9);
  overflow-y: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.pop-up1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.9);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.9);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.9);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.9);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.9);
  overflow-y: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .pop-up {
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
    height: auto;
    max-width: 900px;
  }
}

.pop-up .content {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 900px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .pop-up .content {
    min-height: inherit;
  }
}

.pop-up .content .container {
  padding: 100px 20px 140px;
}

@media (min-width: 568px) {
  .pop-up .content .container {
    padding: 50px 20px 80px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .pop-up .content .container {
    padding: 70px 0px 90px;
    max-width: 520px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}

.pop-up .content .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.05rem;
  color: #3e4146;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.pop-up .content .close:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #f66867;
}

.pop-up .content .dots .dot {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%;
  z-index: 11;
}

.pop-up .content .dots .dot:nth-of-type(1) {
  top: -80px;
  right: -80px;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  background-color: #689bf6;
  -webkit-animation: float 6s ease-in-out infinite;
  -moz-animation: float 6s ease-in-out infinite;
  -o-animation: float 6s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation: float 6s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .pop-up .content .dots .dot:nth-of-type(1) {
    top: -190px;
    right: -190px;
    width: 380px;
    height: 380px;
  }
}

.pop-up .content .dots .dot:nth-of-type(2) {
  bottom: -120px;
  left: -120px;
  width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
  background-color: #f66867;
  -webkit-animation: float 8s ease-in-out infinite;
  -moz-animation: float 8s ease-in-out infinite;
  -o-animation: float 8s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation: float 8s ease-in-out infinite;
}

.pop-up .content .dots .dot:nth-of-type(3) {
  bottom: -50px;
  right: -50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ffd84c;
  -webkit-animation: float 4s ease-in-out infinite;
  -moz-animation: float 4s ease-in-out infinite;
  -o-animation: float 4s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation: float 4s ease-in-out infinite;
}

.pop-up .content .title h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #f66867;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 2.8rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.05rem;
}

.pop-up .content img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 220px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px 0 40px 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(60px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(60px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(60px);
  -o-transform: translateX(60px);
  transform: translateX(60px);
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s;
  transition: 0.2s;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .pop-up .content img {
    max-width: 300px;
  }
}

.pop-up .content .subscribe h1 {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: #3e4146;
  line-height: 130%;
  letter-spacing: 0.07rem;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.pop-up .content .subscribe h1 span {
  color: #f66867;
}

.pop-up .content .subscribe form {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.pop-up .content .subscribe form input {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.05rem;
  outline: 0;
}

.pop-up .content .subscribe form input[type=email] {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #bec1c5;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .pop-up .content .subscribe form input[type=email] {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    width: 75%;
    border-right-width: 0px;
  }
}

.pop-up .content .subscribe form input[type=email]:focus {
  border-color: #3e4146;
}

.pop-up .content .subscribe form input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #8e6ac1;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #8e6ac1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .pop-up .content .subscribe form input[type=submit] {
    width: 25%;
  }
}

.pop-up .content .subscribe form input[type=submit]:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #7349af;
  border-color: #7349af;
}

.pop-up.open {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}

.pop-up.open img {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  -moz-transition: 1s;
  -o-transition: 1s;
  transition: 1s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(0px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0px);
  -o-transform: translateX(0px);
  transform: translateX(0px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="media">
  <div class="media1">
    <ul>
      <li><i class="fab fa-facebook-f" style="font-size: 80px;color: #333333;
    margin-bottom: 10px;"></i></li>
      <li style="color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8);font-size: 26px;font-weight: 600;">Facebook</li>
      <li>
        <div class="button">
          <button><span>Посмотреть цены</span></button>

        </div>

        <div class="pop-up">
          <div class="content">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="dots">
                <div class="dot"></div>
                <div class="dot"></div>
                <div class="dot"></div>
              </div>

              <span class="close">close</span>

              <div class="title">
                <h1>Накрутит в Facebook</h1>
              </div>

              <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/256492/cXsiNryL.png" alt="Car">

              <div class="subscribe">
                <h1>Subscribe to get the latest <span>news &amp; updates</span>.</h1>

                <form>
                  <input type="email" placeholder="Your email address">
                  <input type="submit" value="Subscribe">
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="media1">
    <ul>
      <li><i class="fab fa-facebook-f" style="font-size: 80px;color: #333333;
    margin-bottom: 10px;"></i></li>
      <li style="color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8);font-size: 26px;font-weight: 600;">Instagram</li>
      <li>
        <div class="button">
          <button><span>Посмотреть цены</span></button>
        </div>

        <div class="pop-up">
          <div class="content">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="dots">
                <div class="dot"></div>
                <div class="dot"></div>
                <div class="dot"></div>
              </div>

              <span class="close">close</span>

              <div class="title">
                <h1>Накрутить в инстаграм</h1>
              </div>

              <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/256492/cXsiNryL.png" alt="Car">

              <div class="subscribe">
                <h1>Subscribe to get the latest <span>news &amp; updates</span>.</h1>

                <form>
                  <input type="email" placeholder="Your email address">
                  <input type="submit" value="Subscribe">
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
```